# PassportJS + RestAPI +SPA

Tags: node.js, rest, express, passport.js

I am using ExpressJS to build RestAPI, client is SPA and support authenticate by Google/FaceBook/GitHub/... via PassportJS. My question, callback from social login will return to RestAPI or SPA? If system returns to RestAPI, how can to redirect to home page on SPA. Another case, if system callback SPA, how can RestAPI receive and validate token from client. Please let me know common approachs.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

You provide the callback url to the authentication service, you decide whether you handle the route by the SPA or the API. Oauth authentication (simplified) has two steps. Illustration on github:

Step 1) `https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=*YOUR_CLIENT_ID*$redirect_uri=*YOUR_REDIRECT_URI*`

Opens a popup dialog that requests the user to authorize your application, if successful returns to your redirect_uri with a query parameter ?code=*AUTHORIZATION_CODE*

Step 2)You exchange the above AUTHORIZATION_CODE for a long-term access token via `https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token`

In your architecture, you should do Step 1 in the SPA and Step 2 in the rest api. You should rely on the spa to get the authorization code from the authentication provider, send that to your rest api, let the rest api exchange for a long term access token, save that token to the database, use it to retrieve user information or do whatever you want with it, then log in the user.

For step 1, you only need the CLIENT_ID, for step 2 CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET as well, so you can keep your application secure by storing the CLIENT_SECRET on the server side only.

The problem with having the callback uri handled by your rest api, is that the callback uri is called by the authentication provider (in this case github) and not by your SPA, therefore you can't send a response that redirects the user to the homepage. This would only work if your templates and routing were handled on the server side, which I assume is not the case in your architecture.

It's not obvious from the documentation, but when you register a passport middleware on a route like `app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('github'),`, the middleware will check if the 'code' query param contains an AUTHORIZATION_CODE, if not, it kicks off step 1, if yes step2.

Comment: Thanks Marton, but at step 2, SPA sends token back to rest api, how can rest api verify it? because we can use postman to post invalid token to rest api.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Which token and why do you want to verify it?

Answer (score 2):

I used same stack(express, angular, passport) and followed that approach.

I created a button.

```
<a href="/auth/facebook">Login with facebook</a>
```

Also I have two routes for passport

```
    // send to facebook to do the authentication
  app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', {scope: 'email'}));

  // handle the callback after facebook has authenticated the user
  app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    successRedirect: '/#/profile',
    failureRedirect: '/'  //Redirect Homepage
  }));
```

This code shows that if you login successfully you will be redirect to angular route(/#/profile) After redirect you'll have a cookie which has a token with name connect.sid since passportjs uses express-session.

Then you can check if user logged in everywhere by this middleware

```
// route middleware to ensure user is logged in
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();

  res.redirect(301, '/');
}
```

You can take a look at my repository which contains the code above.
https://github.com/AOnurOzcan/meanTest

If you encounter a problem please let me know.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it